# A media query that is wrongly taken into account

Tags: css

I have an issue with media query. I tried to reproduce it on fiddle without success. So sorry if you have not a fiddle. As I have been searching quite a lot of time, I only expect from you to give me ideas how to resolve it.
I have those media queries

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  input, textarea, .invalid-feedback {
    width: 22vw;
  }
}  

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  input, textarea, .invalid-feedback {
    width: min(16.66vw, 200px);
  } 
}
```

When I display my screen with a width of 782px and lower, the media query @media (min-width: 576px) is taken into account, which is not normal. Do you have an idea ?

### EDIT

I think there is a problem with media queries. I tried the following

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  input, textarea, .invalid-feedback {
    width: 22vw;
  }
  body {
    background-color: red !important;
  }  
}  

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  input, textarea, .invalid-feedback {
    width: min(16.66vw, 200px);
  }
  body {
    background-color: green !important;
  }   
}
```

and I can't see a background color red or green when I have a size of 779px

Comment: "which is not normal" It is? Please elaborate when you want those media queries active!

Comment: Hello, 782px is higher than 576px and 768px, sot the last one (768px) should be taken into account

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue, on a 780px the `(min-width: 768px)` is activated as expected!

Comment: I added a test (see EDIT)

Comment: Finally I re-intalled my browser and everything has gone allright. I don't know what happenned, it seems that my browser was corrupted. The discussion is closed